# multiple bindings one radio button checked event in Knockout JS

Tags: html, css, knockout.js

I have a radio button when checked it makes a div visible, the final input value of this radio button is also used in a modal (if true the modal shows true and vice versa). In my case if the radio button is checked to false it hides the div but displays the value in modal as True which should not happen. Not sure how apply two bindings. Thanks in advance.

HTML:

```
<!--Radio buttons-->
<input  data-bind="checked:abc,checked:xyz" type="radio" name="option1" value="True"> True
<input  data-bind="checked:abc,checked:xyz" type="radio" name="option1" value="False"> False

<!--Div to hide and show-->
<div class="row" style="padding-top:10px;display:none;padding-bottom:10px;padding-left:280px;" data-bind="visible:(xyz()=='True')">
    <div class="col-sm-2">
        <h4 class="header-title m-t-0 m-b-30"IDs:</h4>
        <textarea rows="4" class="form-control" required placeholder="Paste IDs here"></textarea>
    </div>
</div>

<!--Modal-->
<p><strong>IDS:</strong>&nbsp;<span data-bind="text:xyz"></span></p>

Knockout JS:

self.abc= ko.observable("True");
self.xyz= ko.observable();
```

Comment: ok I'm real confused why you want two bindings on your radio button.  I did everything with one binding here https://jsfiddle.net/qpa87ugf/.  so what is missing from that fiddle that you need to accomplish?

Comment: Thank you Brian, there was no need for function xyz.